# Simplest way to make a swipeable tab layout in Android

Tags: java, android, layout, tabs

I know questions around Tabs and swiping are out there, but a lot of them seem far too involved for what I am trying to do. 
Essentially i have two very basic xmls (or i could combine in one if solution allows) that will never change.

I just need a simple 2 tab layout for each xml (or one is even better if possible).

The solutions im finding on the web involve, fragments, PagerView and creating multiple activities and classes. It seems all a bit much considering these xmls will never change over the lifetime of the app. Think, 2 text fields and 2 buttons we are swiping between.

Any very basic solutions out there? Perhaps utilising, ViewAnimator/Switcher somehow with tabs?

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio Go to File-> New -> Activity -> Tabbed Activity

It will open Tabbed activity